# Como contar a quantidade de ocorrências distintas em um BD e retornar

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, group-by

Tenho 3 tabelas em um banco de dados de uma biblioteca. Uma é a tabela membro, com a idadentidade desse membro e uma **PRIMARY KEY num_membro**. A segunda tabela, livro, possui uma **PRIMARY KEY isbn** e o restantes dos atributos **autores** e **editora**. A terceira tabela é uma tabela emprestado, onde possui os atributos **isbn**, como sendo uma chave estrangeira para o atributo isbn da tabela livro e o atributo **num_membro**, sendo chave estrangeira do atributo num_membro da tabela membro.

```
CREATE TABLE livro(
isbn BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
autores VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
editora VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE emprestado(
num_membro INT NOT NULL,
isbn BIGINT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (num_membro) REFERENCES membro(num_membro),
FOREIGN KEY (isbn) REFERENCES livro(isbn));
```

Preciso fazer uma query para *achar os autores que tiveram livros pegos para empréstimo mais de 5 vezes, e os agrupar por editora*.

Fiz duas maneiras:

```
SELECT l.editora, l.autores
FROM emprestado e INNER JOIN livro l ON e.isbn = l.isbn
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(l.autores)
       FROM emprestado e INNER JOIN livro l ON e.isbn = l.isbn) > 5
GROUP BY l.editora, l.autores;
```

Nesse primeiro caso, a tabela também acaba retornando outros autores que não tiveram livros pegos mais de 5 vezes.

```
SELECT l.editora, l.autores
from livro l JOIN emprestado e ON e.isbn = l.isbn
GROUP by l.editora, l.autores
HAVING COUNT(l.autores) > 5;
```

Já esse segundo caso, não é retornado os autores em que seus livros possuem editoras distintas, ou seja, mesmo que esses autores tenham livros pegos mais de 5 vezes, se suas editoras forem diferentes ele não aparece.

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que minha query retorne os autores que tiveram livros pegos mais de 5 vezes, tanto tendo editoras iguais, quanto distintas.

Grata!!

Comment: Creio que sua condição de junção `ON e.num_membro = l.isbn` esteja errada, não deveria ser `ON e.isbn = l.isbn`? Na segunda query creio que você não deveria incluir `autores` em sua cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: Eu vi o JOIN errado e arrumei (obrigada),  mas mesmo assim continuou sem mostrar o autor que possui editoras diferentes. Sobre a segunda query, tirei o l.autores da GROUP BY, ele me informa "42803 column "l.autores" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function", e mesmo se eu tirar esse l.autores também do SELECT, ele ainda não me retorna essas editoras dos autores que quero, somente o que tem a mesma editora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando o PostgreSQL 9.5 ou mais recente pode utilizar a função Count com uma "window function" para obter a quantidade por autores:

```
with CTE_Count as
(
  SELECT 
    l.editora, 
    l.autores, 
    count(*) over(partition by l.autores) as Quantidade
  from livro l 
  inner JOIN emprestado e ON e.isbn = l.isbn
)

select editora, autores
from CTE_Count
where Quantidade > 5
GROUP by editora, autores
```

Espero que ajude